# A stronger generalized Jordan curve theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology

The generalized Jordan curve theorem is usually stated as such:

> Given $X\subseteq S^n$ such that $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^k$, $$\tilde{H}_i(S^n\setminus X)\cong\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z},\quad i=n-k-1 \\ 0,\quad \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

If we relax the hypothesis that $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^k$ and instead only assume that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^k$, does the theorem still hold true? I cannot visualize a counterexample, but I suspect a pathological example may exist. I attempted to prove it using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence like one would for the usual generalized Jordan curve theorem, but ran into an issue in the inductive step:

Let $X\subset S^n$ such that $X\simeq S^k$ and let $f:X\to S^k$ be a homotopy equivalence. Let $A,B\subseteq S^k$ be closed subsets such that $A\cup B=S^k$ and $A\cap B$ is homeomorphic to $S^{k-1}$ (e.g. $A$ and $B$ can closed hemispheres). Then $S^n\setminus f^{-1}(A)$ and $S^n\setminus f^{-1}(B)$ are open subsets of $S^n$ such that $(S^n\setminus f^{-1}(A))\cap(S^n\setminus f^{-1}(B))=S^n\setminus X$. From here, we can use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but in order to use induction on $k$, we need to know that $f^{-1}(A\cap B)$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{k-1}$ and I am not sure whether it is. Also, to make use of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, we would like $S^n\setminus f^{-1}(A)$ and $S^n\setminus f^{-1}(B)$ to have trivial reduced homology, but it is not obvious to me that this should be the case.

Comment: There is a standard argument using Poincare Duality that describes the homology of the compliment in terms of the homology of the submanifold.

Comment: @RyanBudney But that probably requires assuming $X$ is a manifold, right? Perhaps there is a counterexample when $X$ is not a manifold.

Comment: Not really.  It just needs a nice neighbourhood.  For example, it works for CW-complexes.   What kind of spaces $X$ do you want to prove this for?  Look up Alexander-Spanier duality in Bredon's text.

Comment: @RyanBudney I am looking at arbitrary subspaces of $S^n$ which are homotopy equivalent to $S^k$, no additional structure.

Comment: If you assume that $X$ is compact, you get the desired conclusion, otherwise, I am doubtful.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What about compactness implies the desired conclusion?

Comment: In this case: Use Alexander duality for Chech cohomology and the fact that Chech cohomology is homotopy invariant.